# Сортировка товаров в React Redux приложении

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Друзья,всем доброго времени суток,нужно реализовать сортировку товаров по увеличению и уменьшению цены.Как написать такой акшен.?
Я пробовал в акшене писать сортровку массива объектов с помощью метода sort.Сам масcив создается в сторе с помощью React хука UseEffect вторым параметром в UseEffect я передал этот самый массив,но перерисовка происходит только когда мы переходим в корзину а в риал тайме перерисовки мы не видим.Подскажите что делаю не так?
Вот сам компонент который загружает товары в стор и отрисовывает их:

```
function Home() {
    const books = useSelector(state=>state.books.books);
    const isFetched = useSelector(state=>state.books.isFetched);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(()=>{
      if(!books.length ){
        dispatch(setBooks())
      } 
    },[books]
);
    

    return (
       
      <Card.Group itemsPerRow={5}>
                {!isFetched ?  <Loader/> : books.map(i=>(<Books title = {i.title}
                 key={i.id}
                 author={i.author} 
                 image={i.image} 
                 price={i.price}
                 rating={i.rating}
                 />))}
        </Card.Group>
    );
}
```

А вот редьюсер в котором написана сортировка и санка для загрузки товаров в стор:

```
const initialState = {
    books: [],
    isFetched: false,
}

export const SET_BOOKS = 'SET_BOOKS';


export const setBooks = (books) =>{
    return async dispatch => {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/books');
        const json = await response.json();
        dispatch({
            type: SET_BOOKS,
            payload: json
        });
    }
 }
  
 const SET_FILTER_LOWER = 'SET_FILTER_LOWER';

 export const setFilter = filter => ({
   type: SET_FILTER_LOWER,
   payload: filter,
 });

 export const setBooksReducer = (state = initialState, action) =>{
     switch(action.type){
        case SET_BOOKS:
            return {...state, 
                books: state.books.concat(action.payload),
                isFetched: true
            }
        case SET_FILTER_LOWER:
        return {
          ...state,
          books: action.payload.sort((a,b)=>a.price-b.price)
        //   books: action.payload.filter((el)=>el.price<=300)
        };
        default: 
        return state

     }
      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

а где диспатч фильтра? Если вы его просто забыли показать, то скорее всего дело в том, что функция sort мутабельная, и компонент просто не видит изменений:

```js
let a = [1, 5, 3];
let b = a.sort();

console.log(a==b);

a = [1, 5, 3];
b = [...a].sort();

console.log(a == b);
```